# Industry standards a self taught android developer should learn | Android studio, kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, conventions

I'm a self-taught android developer, I want to work as an android developer but I have some imposter syndrome. I think there should be coding conventions we should follow when we code, like:

- Follow any architecture (MVP or MVVP)
- Coding best practices (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html)
- Using architecture components like LiveCycle, LiveData, Room, etc ...
- Design with XML? (For now, I just export images and use them as design, an example: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbC5f.png))
  etc ...

I search on internet about coding convention and I only found this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html (Are they the only standars I need to follow ?)

I also try to look for professional android project I could read, but The only one I found on github is this one : https://github.com/Yazan98/Wintrop (And I don't know if I can take it as reference).

**Can I still be hired** **without this knowledge****? If I need to learn them, what else should I learn to match industry standards? What information should I know about industry standards as a self-taught android developer?**

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You see even tho i think you tried your best, to ask this question, i think this is the wrong forum for this type of questions.
Please read the tour:
https://stackoverflow.com/tour

To quote: 
Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers.

Comment: You dont need all the things you mentioned. Well it depends on where you wanna work and which work..

Comment: I recommend asking about this on a forum (like `reddit.com/r/android_devs`) or on the Android Developers Discord channel. It's considered off-topic for StackOverflow because it is an open-ended and opinion-based question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; should I delete the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, standards there are several for example [Modern Android App Architecture](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/android-architecture) that I highly recommend you but also you can find something else like [Guide to Android app modularization](https://developer.android.com/topic/modularization) which is also important in the modern android applications creation.

For projects you can look at [nowinandroid](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) which is just very well done and [this](https://github.com/android/compose-samples) too it's some models that google's engineers have made for new learners it's really very well done all the standards are respected and they use the new technology in this project like [jetpack compose](https://github.com/jetpack-compose/jetpack-compose-awesome) instead of old *XML*, [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) for local data storage, [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore?gclid=Cj0KCQiA1sucBhDgARIsAFoytUsMeB4Uvb7JqAjiCzA1GXNpeUKoZbMeF5GWpstJpOZZTL7tLDolGzIaAuL_EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) for preferences, [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs?gclid=Cj0KCQiA1sucBhDgARIsAFoytUvshbWrV9s9FgvqX2_lflj08QI7-YPun0Y01dusUtN3Zwln2f8IL4YaAhx8EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)...

I highly recommend these links

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I got an idea for most of the information I was looking for!